# Missing Google Apps Script source, deployed app works, how to recover?

Tags: google-apps-script

I use the https://script.google.com editor to edit my Google Apps Scripts.  One of my scripts is 'missing' and I can not find it anywhere on my Google Drive.  The 'deployed web app' continues to work though.  Is there any means to recover this script so that I can edit it again?

On 2 October 2015, I used the 'Make a copy' option within script.google.com for this script to branch it off for another project.  I am worried that this step may have removed the previous script's source?  I just now tried a test of this action and it properly resulted in two distinct scripts.  Hmmm.

For my 'copied' script, I did save an initial revision of it within script.google.com, so perhaps I could revert back to that revision and get a close copy to what I started off with.  But I can not figure out how to revert the code back to that revision either.

Here's an image of what shows on drive.google.com for the copied script.
[image]

Comment: If the script is bound to a Spreadsheet, Form or Doc, the script will not show up in your drive.  You can have a script bound to a document, and still deploy it as a web app.  Have you used the "search" field to look for the file?

Comment: Indeed, I do either the "File -> Open" within the script.google.com editor and the Google Drive search "type: script" and it is not located.  I was editing it via script.google.com up until the copy being made.

Comment: Is it possible that it's in the trash, or in a different account?

Comment: Not in trash, nor in other google accounts I have.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that you can run to search for the file:

```
function getTheFile() {
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "Partial Name Here"');

 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   Logger.log(file.getName());
 }
};
```

Where it states:  "Partial Name Here" Enter the name of the file, or a partial text of the file name.

If you can find the file in code, and you own it, you can make a copy of it with DriveApp.

Comment: Did not find it, nor when I search on drive.google.com via web UI