# How do I download previous saved revisions of a Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am still attempting to recover from [somehow 'loosing' a Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33697789/) when I created a copy of the script to fork the code to another project...  My thought was to attempt to download older revisions of the Google Apps Script via the drive API, but [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export) indicates that perhaps it is not possible.

> *Actions such as versioning, publishing or executing the script are not available through the API.*

So I attempted it anyway and alas this error occurs...

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting 
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/..snipped../revisions?alt=json
returned "File does not support revisions">
```

So is there no mechanism to download previous versions or "Revisions" of Google Apps Script?  What I would love is to get access to 'Revision 1' shown here within the script.google.com interface:

[image]

Comment: You can avoid all of this hassle by just backing up your source files as separate ascii files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68929627/7215091

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FYI, the Apps Script API can get project files from a previous version number:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent

If you'd like to see this in the Apps Script CLI, clasp, like `clasp pull 3`, I'm sure I could add this feature.
https://github.com/google/clasp/
Just file a new issue.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to address this old question :)

Answer (score 16):

This is a bit manual but:

- Create another script project
- [Include your original script as a library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries) in your new script and select v1
- In the new script add some code that uses your "library"
- Use the script editor debugger to step into the library and you should see the code from the correct version

For example if your library is called something like "MyOldCode", include some code like this in your new script:

```
function getOldCode() {
  var a = MyOldCode.anExampleFunction()
}
```

Put a breakpoint below the "var a" line, run getOldCode() with the debugger and then step into anExampleFunction(). This will open up one file of your old code allowing you to copy and paste it elsewhere.

You can then piece together v1.

Edit 2019-04-11: There is also [Romain's function for accessing old versions](https://github.com/RomainVialard/access-code-of-older-versions).

Edit 2022-05-05: With V8 and the new editor I can no longer find a way to step into a library. Rhino gives a server error, and V8 ignores the "step in".

Comment: This saved my ass just now. Thank you!

Comment: In the last step, where do you see the code? @Andrew Roberts

Comment: Thank you very much @Andrew Roberts :)

Comment: I'll also add to this a bit...
I forgot what functions I had in the old code so if you 

 1. open Resources -> Libraries
 2. click the link to your old code (see my STSTrackerApp insert below

You will get the functions defined and even by version.

Image here -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yojla.png

Comment: You can also use ``Logger.log(MyOldCode.anExampleFunction)``

Comment: I couldn't work out why this wasn't working for me - the code I was seeing after following these steps was the newest version! Turns out I was using the library in "Development Mode", which always uses the current state of the code, and not the version specified. So make sure to turn "Development Mode" to "Off"!

Comment: In the last step, I'm unable to see the code, too.

Answer (score 0):

Grant is the right answer. Clasp is the way. I just wanted to update the command for the current state of clasp which is

```
clasp pull --versionNumber 12
```